# Reverting back to original AMD Ubuntu 16.04 drivers

Tags: drivers, radeon

There was this bizarre issue with an Ubuntu 16.04 update where my graphics drivers where updated and then it crippled the dual display configuration leaving me without one of the displays. I know what it is and it's that it installed a new edition of the AMD graphics driver upon update, these driver's are just not ready, they are finnicky with dual display stuff and I need them off, this was the same deal with 18.04 where my dual displays setup wasn't working, now it's happening but with 16.04 under the update. So the solution here is to just revert to the original graphics drivers 16.04 included via terminal, I am unsure how to revert back to the original driver via terminal... Any body wanna give it a shot?

Card is Radeon Pro WX2100.

Comment: Are you asking about the AMDGPU-PRO proprietary drivers?

Comment: I am not entirely sure. Neither would it matter as what I am strictly looking for is just reverting back to the drivers that 16.04 shipped, whether they where the PRO drivers or some open driver, which ever one shipped with 16.04 upon install, I need it back.

Comment: Try adding `amdgpu.dc=0` to the kernel command at boot. You really do not want to revert back to the kernel version which originally shipped on the release ISO. It is rife with security issues which have since been fixed. It's also hard to help you when nobody knows what version of 16.04 you installed, or whether or not you installed HWE stack at some point.

Comment: I am using 16.04LTS, I am not entirely sure about how to check for HWE stack. I don't need it down to the original kernel but just the graphics driver and I am having a hard time understanding how to revert to the last driver that was installed before the update, I am unsure of how to about checking for the versions of previous drivers installed through the terminal, fetching that version of the AMD driver and then bringing it back and do a sudo restart. The issue is sorted, all I need is the previous driver returned to operation, nothign else.

Comment: The graphics driver is multiple parts. Part of it is in the kernel. Part of it is in xorg. Please try booting with `amdgpu.dc=0` on the kernel command line. You can edit the boot command at the grub prompt, and append after the `quiet splash` part. Or you can edit `/etc/default/grub` to add it to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` then run `update-grub` and reboot, to test.